# Convert edited PDF into TXT

Tags: python, pdf, type-conversion

I’m trying to compile some code to convert PDF to text, but the result is not what I expected. I have tried different libraries such as pytesseract, pdfminer, pdftotext, pdf2image, and OpenCV, but all of them extract the text incompletely or with errors. The last two codes that I used are these:

```
def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
  text = extract_text(path)
  return text

# Change the file path according to the location of your PDF file
pdf_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/PDF/file.pdf'

# Convert the PDF to text
text = convert_pdf_to_txt(pdf_path)

# Write the text to a file
with open('extracted_text.txt', 'w') as file:
file.write(text)

# Print a confirmation message
print('The text has been saved to the "extracted_text.txt" file.')
```

However, when I use online PDF to text converters, the conversion comes out very well, almost perfect, without the errors that I encounter in both codes. Here I attach the PDF that I want to convert to text and the results that I get from both codes when I try to convert my file.

These are the attached documents:

https://anonfiles.com/P09bnen5z6/file_pdf
https://anonfiles.com/g7Aan6n5ze/Archive_txt

I’m trying to compile some code to convert PDF to text, but the result is not what I expected. I have tried different libraries such as pytesseract, pdfminer, pdftotext, pdf2image, and OpenCV, but all of them extract the text incompletely or with errors. The last two codes that I used are these:

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no errors with dump PDFtoTEXT, but depends how its used and commanded plus quality of source PDF which if faulty it cannot edit to correct, that needs to be done before or after extraction.

I will not dump the full page(s) due to the personal data so forgive the ####

```
DOCUMENT #2021.07.B




P.O. Box ####, Altamonte Springs, FL #### Office:
(407) 2##-#### - Fax: (407) 6##-#### Email:
####@A##Q######A########.com
Florida Licensed #### ######### MRSA ####
Florida Licensed Engineering Firm COA #####
                                                                                    CUSTOMER INFO

  Client Name: C#### G#####                                                                                                       Date: ## / ## / 202#

  Address: #### Southwest ##### ###                                                    City: #### City                                              Zip: #####

  Home Phone:                                                  Cell Phone: 401-###-####                                     Email: ###@###.com

  Insurance Company: Frontline                                                                      Date of Loss: #/##/202#

  Policy #: 010000#####                                                                             Claim #: FPH3-0000#####



                                                                                 CONTRACT FOR SERVICES
I, the Homeowner/Insured, and/or its representative for the property listed above (hereinafter “Client”), authorize Air Quality Assessors of Florida, its subcontractors and/or assignees
(hereinafter collectively referred to as “AQA”), to enter said property to perform assessment services, including but not limited to indoor environmental assessments, asbestos testing,
engineering inspections and post-mitigation verification. Client and AQA hereby acknowledge that the services to be provided are NOT being provided in an urgent or emergency circumstance
as defined by 627.7152. Client agrees to fully cooperate with insurance company as required by the subject policy of insurance and comply with all post-loss duties required by same. Clients
understands that the assessment services to be rendered are directly related and necessary as a result of the above-referenced loss and that it should provide a copy of any report prepared
by AQA to its repair contractors to ensure a complete and proper repair of the damage to the subject property and to obtain any necessary building permits.


                                                ASSIGNMENT OF INSURANCE CLAIM BENEFITS & DIRECT PAY AUTHORIZATION
```

In my right click "sendto" folder `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` I have a shortcut to a cmd script that accepts a PDF file and runs

```
cd /d "%~dp1"
"C:\Apps\PDF\poppler\23.01.0\Library\bin\pdftotext.exe" -layout -enc UTF-8 -nopgbrk "%~dpn1.pdf"
echo continue to open in notepad
pause
notepad "%~dpn1.txt"
```

For windows users the easy zipped binaries are at https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows or you can use the conda variants if newer.

Comment: Hello K J ! How did you do that? What library did you use? Could you give me a hand? That's amazing!!!

Comment: K J, THANKS A LOT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Seriously thank you!!!!! man!! it's working!!!

Comment: Hello K J. The code seems to be working fine, however, I noticed that it doesn't work when attempting to convert other types of PDFs that only contain text. My question is, is it feasible to enhance the code to support the conversion of different types of PDFs, including the one attached to this email?

https://anonfiles.com/scW2b0paz6/Copy_of_AOB_pdf

the other type of documents have converted successfully! :D

Comment: No worries, K J. Thanks for your response. It turns out that I've been trying to convert a massive amount of PDFs into text, but unfortunately, not all of them have the same format. Some of them have a good digital text format that works excellently with the first code you shared with me. However, for other types of PDFs, like the one I sent you previously, the code isn't converting properly. So, I tried to adapt your last code to Python subprocess.call(["pdftoppm", "-png", "-r", "300", pdf_path, "out"]). It worked well for "Copy_of_AOB_pdf," but not for "file.pdf" and other types of PDFs.

Comment: Okay, I understand. What code may I use to work with documents like anonfiles.com/scW2b0paz6/Copy_of_AOB_pdf and https://anonfiles.com/r7Q8l0p7z7/file_pdf with the same quality as the first code you provided? I am currently working on creating a code that can identify whether a PDF document is considered textual or scanned, so the program can convert it using the code you shared and the other code I have developed for converting PDFs to text, but in case it has been scanned, such as anonfiles.com/scW2b0paz6/Copy_of_AOB_pdf. However, it would make me ease to adapt your first code to convert  it

Comment: Hello K J. What would you suggest I do in this case? Checking document by document will be a daunting task as there are over 10,000 PDFs to go through. I have been working on developing a programme to recognise which PDFs can be treated as only text, scanned or hybrid, and then apply the appropriate conversion code for each situation.

Comment: I have two codes to convert PDFs to text. The first one you shared, and the second one is to convert PDFs into images, then into text but I have been having some difficulties completing it, which is why I am considering using machine learning. I do not know what logic to use, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PyPDF2`'s `PdfReader` and `extract_text`:

```
!pip install PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DATA_FOLDERS/PDF/some_pdf_doc.pdf')
page = reader.pages[0]
extracted_text = page.extract_text()
```

`print(extracted_text)` outputs:

```
Some text in the first sentence. This is the second sentence, and also the last sentence.
```

which we can save as a `txt` file using `numpy`'s `savetxt`:

```
file_name = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DATA_FOLDERS/PDF/some_new_pdf_doc.txt'
import numpy as np
np.savetxt(file_name, [extracted_text], fmt='%s')
```

We can read the new `txt` file using `numpy`'s `loadtxt`:

```
import numpy as np
some_txt_doc = np.loadtxt('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DATA_FOLDERS/PDF/some_new_pdf_doc.txt', dtype=str, delimiter=';;;')
print(some_txt_doc)
```

Outputs:

```
Some text in the first sentence. This is the second sentence, and also the last sentence.
```

Comment: Hello Ori,

I attempted to run your code, but the output is still messy and disorganised. The text is not formatted correctly.

I have attached the file for your review.

https://anonfiles.com/MfS5Cbn8z8/file_txt

Comment: @Olivalej what specifically? If you mean the line spacing and centering, that might be unavoidable as a `.txt` file. If you mean the page(s) numbering then I can edit my answer. The only other difference I noticed was that a space (' ') is added before a '-'.

Comment: Ori, this is my point:

Client Name:  Date: 
Address:  City:  Zip: 
Home Phone:  Cell Phone:  Email: 
Insurance Company:  Date of Loss:   
Policy #:  Claim #:  
Craig Gaunya Gaunya
1586 Southwest Egret Way Palm City 34990
401-741-8841 wishbonemkt@aol.com
Frontline 4/11/2021
01000048082 FPH3-000037943
Craig Gaunya Gaunya
10 / 18 / 2021
10 / 18 / 2021

Comment: As you can see, the order is not correct when compared to the result obtained from an online converter.

This is the result from an online converser: https://anonfiles.com/5e4aEdn7z9/file_1_txt

Comment: oof... I'm not sure I know of any better `pdf` libraries.

Comment: :( I've been at it for ages, but I still haven't got the results I was hoping for.
Can someone give me a hand, please? I'm really stuck here :(

Comment: I'll update my answer if I can find one.